# RegExp: Match repeating sequence pattern of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to write an RegExp that matches something like `01, 03, 05-08, 10` but does not match `01, 03, 05-08,` (because the squence has to end with a number).

So basically my "string" consists of `/(\-?\d+)\-(\-?\d+)/` (e.g. 01-05 or -5-10) every instance of this pattern is seperated by a comma.

I tried a looong time with RegExr but couldn't find a solution for my problem. Here is my try: http://regexr.com?34hh1

With the RegExp I want to do SEQUENCE_EXP.test('some string').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern this is exact requirement as you specified

```
^(-?\d+(--?\d+)?,\s?)*-?\d+(--?\d+)?$
```

Live Demo: http://regexr.com?34hhp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$` operator to indicate the string has to end with the expression. In your case you could try:

```
/^((-?\d+(-\d+)?)\s*,\s*)+(-?\d+(-\d+)?)$/
```

Note that you don't have to escape the `-` outside of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two patterns, a valid number `\d+` And `\d+-\d+`

So the `NUMBER_PATTERN` must be `\d+(-\d+)?`

And a sequence `NUMBER_PATTERN[, NUMBER_PATTERN]*`

What about this:

```
/\d+(-\d+)?(, \d+(-\d+)?)*$/
```

Take a look http://regexr.com?34hhj

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,)*\d+$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/QTnbqncycZ

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(r){
    return  "01, 03, 05-08, 10".match(r) && 
            !"01, 03, 05-08,".match(r)
}

test(/^(\d+(-\d+)?,\s*)*\d+$/)
```